# draw.io: cannot open xml file from URL (using the parameter "url=...." )

Tags: url, draw.io

I've installed draw.io on a local web server and want to open a xml file which resides on the same web server. 
The [documentation](https://support.draw.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12878136) proposes the URL parameter `url=url`

This is my xml file:

```
https://draw.io.myorg/folder/test.xml
https%3A%2F%2Fdraw.io.myorg%2Ffolder%2Ftest.xml (encoded)
```

This is the URL which uses the URL parameter url=...

```
https://draw.io.myorg/folder/draw.io-master/war/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdraw.io.myorg%2Ffolder%2Ftest.xml
```

The above URL ends up with the message "file not found".

Same error if I try to open this URL via "Open->From URL".

When I store the xml into a local file, I can open it with "Open-> Device ..."

However, the web server and the browser show me a failure when opening this file:

```
https://mdraw.io.myorg/folder/draw.io-master/war/proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdraw.io.myorg%2Ffolder%2Ftest.xml
```

Obviously the parameter `url` causes some redirection to a proxy which does not exist?

Any help is appreciated!